# Unable to load images from local library in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have written a code for my website and unfortunately, i am not able to load images that are located in my local library. I have moved my images folder inside 'src' folder, but the image doesn't load at all.

Here is the code for my component called 'Landscape' which I am trying to load.

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Grid, Button, Row, Col, Thumbnail} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'react-bootstrap-carousel';
import './Landscape.css';

export default class Landscape extends Component{
render(){
return(
<div className="thumbnails">
  <Grid>
    <Row>
      <Col xs={6} md={4}>
        <Thumbnail src=".Pictures/1.jpg" alt="242x240">
        <h3>Elephant</h3>
        <p>zoo</p>
        <p>
          <Button bsStyle="primary">Like</Button>
          {' '}
          <Button bsStyle="primary">Dislike</Button>
        </p>
        </Thumbnail>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Grid>
</div>

);
}}
```

Comment: are you using webpack or something like that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `./Pictures/1.jpg`? And hopefully you're only expecting this to work in development mode.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: did you save your images directly in src folder or made a folder for them? because your path is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a few images you can just import it directly in your component

```
import logo from './Pictures/1.jpg';
```

Then call it

```
<img src={logo} alt="logo" width={"240"} height={"240"}  />
```

if you have hundreds of images because you can’t use import paths, you have to create a images folder in the public folder and use this code.

```
 //This is the regular way.

  <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'images/profile.svg'} width={"200"} height={"200"} className="profile-img" alt="profile" />
```

**Another way** you can specify each component has a `images.js` file, then import all the images that retarded of that component in `images.js` and  name it as the related component name

images.js

```
import logo from './images/logo.svg';
import cover from './images/cover.svg';
import profile from './images/profile.svg';
import background1 from './images/body.svg';
export default {
    logo,
    cover,
    profile,
    background1
}
```

Then in your component you can just import `images.js file`:

```
import images from './images';
```

Then call any img you want:

```
      <img src={images.logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <img src={images.cover} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <img src={images.profile} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <img src={images.background1} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried and it worked. What if i have 50 images to be shown as thumbnails ? importing every image would take more time and suppose in future, if i need to replace some of them would take more time. isn't there any other way to pull images ?

Comment: @PruthviRajGowda If you have 50 images, you should consider managing them through a database and automate the process of loading & displaying them in your component.

Comment: Or at the very least reference them in a JSON file, either in an array if you just want to iterate over all images, or in key/value pairs if you want to access images individually.

Comment: @PruthviRajGowda I just edited my answer, check it out

Comment: Thank you so much for you response! I am doing it the way you have explained. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

My answer only applies if you are using `create-react-app` or Webpack with the `file-loader` plugin.

You have to import the picture file before using it. This has to be done in order for Webpack to bundle the images correctly for the production build.

```
import pic1 from './Pictures/1.jpg';
...
<Thumbnail src={pic1} alt="242x240">
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files).

Answer (score 0):

Put all your images in one 'images' folder under the public folder, then anywhere in your project, you can use the following path in **img** element:

It works fine with projects initiate with **create-react-app**