# First Time React, Coming from Angular. CSS Grid?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can I style a component to lay out subcomponents in a grid?

I've been trying to do it multiple ways:

## Method 1:

1. Import custom CSS Stylesheet - in the parent component, I'm importing the stylesheet with: `import './style.css'` (not the actual file, but it get's the point across.)
2. Target and apply styles: Should be as simple as `.targetClassName{display:grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);}`

In my experience, it doesn't make it to the DOM.

## Method 2:

1. Set a style as an object: `const style = { display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)'};`
2. Apply  inline to the component: `<div className='items' style={this.style}></div>`

for some reason isn't working as well.

Just for some background, this is the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Computer from './computer';

import './styles/computers.sass';


class Computers extends Component{

  deleteComputer(_id){
    this.props.onDelete(_id);
  }


  render(){
    const compListStyle = {
      display: 'grid',
      gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)'
    }
    let computerList;
    if(this.props.computers){
      computerList = this.props.computers.map(x => {
        console.log(x);
        return(
          <Computer computer={x} onDelete={this.deleteComputer.bind(this)}/>
        )
      })
    }
    return(
      <div className='computers' style={this.compListStyle}>
        {computerList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Computers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are many ways to use CSS in react I just don't prefer you to keep your styles inside `render()` keep it out of your component

```
 const compListStyle = {
      display: 'grid',
      gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)'
    }

class Computers extends Component{ ...}
```

And use them like

```
 <div className='computers' style={compListStyle}>
    {computerList}
  </div>
```

As well when you're iterating data don't keep them in `render()`

```
   {this.props.computers && this.props.computers.map(x => {
                console.log(x);
                return (
                <div>
                <Computer computer={x} onDelete={this.deleteComputer.bind(this)}/>
                </div>)}
                )}
```

Here's final code very clean and small

```
const compListStyle = {
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)'
};

class Computers extends Component {
    deleteComputer(_id) {
        this.props.onDelete(_id);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.computers && this.props.computers.map(x => {
                    console.log(x);
                    return (
                        <div className='computers' style={compListStyle}>
                            <Computer computer={x} onDelete={this.deleteComputer.bind(this)}/>
                        </div>)}
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Computers;
```

As well here are some tips

[ReactJS Folder structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141034/reactjs-folder-structures/49143281#49143281)

[Handle hundreds of images in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121341/unable-to-load-images-from-local-library-in-react-js/48121563#48121563)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class variable in styles object. So you should set it to one too.

```
this.compListStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)'
}
```

The first method should be working if you are using a style-loader/sass-loader to load the style files.

Comment: Just Happy to Help