# React components folder structure

Tags: reactjs

What is the best folder structure to use with my components in a React app?

I'm learning react now and I'm trying to convert a Bootstrap theme ([Jumbotron](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/jumbotron/)) to React.

This template has a navbar that has some links and a search bar, so I created a navbar component, a NavBarMenu (component) and a NavBarSearch (component). The folder structure looks like:

[image: folder structure]

This is the best way to start? or i should create a NavBar folder, and inside it create a NavBarMenu and NavBarSearch?

just like this:

```
src
/components
/NavBar
 index.js
 /NavBarMenu
  index.js
 /NavBarSearch
  index.js
```

Which is the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: There is no best one. Some just put all the component together into one folder, others go for structuring them into different folders, sometimes nested .. Depends totally on your needs and tastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make my Nav a container. If you ever plan to have things dynamically / conditionally shown on your Navbar, you'll need to be using state to keep track of them.

The Nav container is responsible for different types of navigation I might want to present, so I can have either a NavBar at the top, or a SideNav for mobile layouts.

The Nav container knows if you want to show a login / sign-up link, or a link to the profile with the username & picture.

My NavBar Component then is responsible for laying out all of the links, or sub-components like a search bar or profile link.

```
-Containers
  -Nav / Nav.js
-Components
  -Nav
    -NavBar / NavBar.js NavBar.css
    -NavSearch / NavSearch.js NavSearch.css
    -NavProfile / NavProfile.js NavProfile.css
```

Don't get to hung up on the details of the folder structure. While it is important, it ultimately has nothing to do with the end product being served to the user. The folder structure needs to be consistent, and make sense to you and anyone else working on the project.

Far more important than the folder structure is the logical structure of your containers & components. Make sure you put plenty of though into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sub directories to organize your logic, then yes, this would be a great directory structure. But I would warn against over abstraction. If you don't need to use a component in multiple places it might not need its own file.

Another approach, rather than creating whole sub directories is to just create files for the sub components, like this:

```
- Nav
 - __tests__
 - NavBar.js
 - NavBarMenu.js
 - NavBarSearch.js
```

Also I'm just gonna leave this here because I think you could use it. You can use it with or without webpack. It's very nice to have:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias#usage-with-webpack

Answer (score 0):

To make React Application maintainable, i am following below folder structure:

```
src
 
 -assets
 
  --images
 
-components
 
  --container - This will have all logical components
 
  --presentation - This will have all view components
 
-services index.js - All end point call will come here
```

I found this best folder structure [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220418235835/http://musttoknow.com/create-a-new-react-app-with-best-folder-structure-for-beginners/).