# How to load an image using relative path in ReactJS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to add two images 1)java.png 2)neural.png When I try to type in `src="java.png"` and `src="neural.png"` it does not load the image. I want to add these images in my content component.

content.js:

```
class Content extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div> 

                     <div className="col l4">
                            <img src="java.png" alt="Java" height="25" width="25"></img>
                            <h6 className="cardtitle1">NEW LAUNCH</h6>
                            <p className="cardcontent1">JAVA</p><p></p>
                            <p className="cardcontent1">Foundations</p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col l4">
                            <img src="neural.png" alt="Neural Network" height="25" width="25"></img>
                            <h6 className="cardtitle2">NEW LAUNCH</h6>
                            <p className="cardcontent2">Neural Newtwork</p><p></p>
                            <p className="cardcontent2">Foundations</p>
                      </div>
 </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

The file path looks like this:

[image]

In console it shows image could not load:
[image]

Comment: Are you using ```create-react-app```?

Comment: @salman.zare Yes

Comment: Have you imported the image? like this:

```import java from './java.png';``` 

And then:
```<img src={java} alt="Java" />```

Comment: @salman.zare Should I make images.js and then import it ?

Comment: No, please refer to the following reference:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files

Comment: @salman.zare Can you please help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229529/how-to-add-multiple-images-from-external-js-file-in-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment85462990_49229529

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are many ways to handle images in ReactJS.

```
import Java from './java.png';
```

then use it like

```
  <img src={Java} alt="Java" height="25" width="25" />
```

Also check of this link will help you [Unable to load images from local library in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121341/unable-to-load-images-from-local-library-in-react-js/48121563#48121563)

Comment: Can you please help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229529/how-to-add-multiple-images-from-external-js-file-in-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment85462990_49229529

Answer (score 1):

I put all my images in one 'images' folder under the public folder, then anywhere in my project, I can use the following path in **img** element:

It works fine with my projects initiate with **create-react-app** especially when I have too many images, then I don't have to import one by one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <img src="./java.png" alt="Java" height="25" width="25"></img>
```